# My Sql Query - Insert new record in table under specific conditions from other two tables and avoid duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am going nuts trying to figure out this all day but without success.

I have 3 tables called: selections, auctions, game

What I need to achieve is insert 3 new records in 'selections' table for every game which is written in 'auctions' table (they are marked in both tables with ID number) but some necessary data is also in 'game' table which is connected with 'auctions' table (with BetfairMark). And to avoid duplicate entry if there are any.

'***Auctions***' table have this columns: 
**id** (writen in table from before and it's connection with 'selections' table) 
**BetfairMark** (must be the same as 'BetfairMarketID' from 'game' to properly connect 'auctions' table with 'game' table),
**title** (written in table from before)

'***Selections***' table have columns:
**id** (which is auto-increasing number for every new record generated in this table),
**auctionid** (this is number which must be created here with this query to be the same as is 'id' from auctions table)
**order** (each of 3 records must have generated with query order numbers 1, 2, 3)
**odds** (need to get proper odds number for each record from Game table)

'***Game***' table have this columns:
**BetfairMarketID** (which need to be the same number as 'BetfairMark' from auctions table to figure out right row to take data from this table)
**ABack** (odds number which need to go in selections new record under 'order' 1)
**BBack** (odds number which need to go in selections new record under 'order' 2)
**DrawBack** (odds number which need to go in selections new record under 'order' 3)

To summarize need to achieve this:
- insert 3 new records in 'selections' table where every record need to be marked with order 1, 2 and 3. Must show there proper 'auctionid' number according to auctions table relationship.
- if there will be duplicate record entry (by this mean some record will have same 'auctionid' number AND same 'order' number record will not be inserted.
- in those 3 new records must input 'odds' numbers from 'ABack', 'BBack', 'DrawBack' columns in 'game' table (which is in relationship with 'auctions' table according to BetfairMarketID/BetfairMark same number).

I tryed this which hoping is on right track but need a lot of modifications:

```
INSERT INTO selections (selections.auctionid, selections.order, selections.odds)
VALUES 
((SELECT id FROM auctions), '1', (select ABack FROM game, auctions WHERE game.BetfairMarketID = auctions.BetfairMark)),
((SELECT id FROM auctions), '2', (select BBack FROM game, auctions WHERE game.BetfairMarketID = BetfairMark)),
((SELECT id FROM auctions), '3', (select DrawBack FROM game, auctions WHERE game.BetfairMarketID = BetfairMark))
```

But receiving this error: [Err] 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Simple clarification: With query need to have 3 records in 'selection' table for each auctionid (given in 'auction' table). Each of those 3 records need to have different order numbers (1, 2 and 3) and different odds numbers (given from 'game' table). No duplicate entries allowed (where same auctionid AND order number would be).

Comment: (Apparently the OP has not solved their problem yet, since they were asking again here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669470/transform-mysql-query-into-php-command - bounty added to help them get an answer.)

Comment: @Ivy if it is solved please mark your answer as accepted to help others having same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED!
Created 3 separated queries for each row, working for now!

So with added UNIQUE INDEX to the (auctionid, order) pair have this workable code:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO
selections
(
selections.auctionid,
selections.order,
selections.title,
startamount
)
SELECT
auctions.id,
1,
PlayerA,
0.01
FROM
auctions, game
WHERE
auctions.BetfairMark = game.BetfairMarketID
;

INSERT IGNORE INTO
elections
(
selections.auctionid,
selections.order,
selections.title,
startamount
)
SELECT
auctions.id,
2,
PlayerB,
0.01
FROM
auctions, game
WHERE
auctions.BetfairMark = game.BetfairMarketID
;

INSERT IGNORE INTO
selections
(
selections.auctionid,
selections.order,
selections.title,
startamount
)
SELECT
auctions.id,
3,
'third text',
0.01
FROM
auctions, game
WHERE
auctions.BetfairMark = game.BetfairMarketID
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a PHP tag, I'll assume that using some PHP code to process this is a possibility.

Use PHP to run the following query

```
SELECT id, BetfairMarketID FROM game
```

Then, iterate over each row and do this:

```
INSERT INTO selections (selections.auctionid, selections.order, selections.odds)
VALUES 
((SELECT id FROM auctions WHERE BetfairMark = $BetfairMarketID), '1', (select ABack FROM game WHERE id = $id)),
((SELECT id FROM auctions WHERE BetfairMark = $BetfairMarketID), '2', (select BBack FROM game WHERE id = $id)),
((SELECT id FROM auctions WHERE BetfairMark = $BetfairMarketID), '3', (select DrawBack FROM game WHERE id = $id))
```

If I understood what you're trying to do, this should work. Leave a comment if I'm wrong!

Comment: Uh. It was not my intention to do it in PHP. But could try in PHP for the first time! Can you be so kind and give me example of full PHP code for this?

Comment: Still dont understand how to use this query and iterate over each row. What you mean by this? I know how to put usual mysql query with PHP but not sure how to adapt this query for PHP. Can someone help?

Comment: **Tryed this but not working:** 
mysql_query
("
`SELECT id, BetfairMarketID FROM game

{
INSERT INTO selections (selections.auctionid, selections.order, selections.odds)
VALUES 
    {
    ((SELECT id FROM auctions WHERE BetfairMark = $BetfairMarketID), '1', (select ABack FROM game WHERE id = $id)),
        {
        ((SELECT id FROM auctions WHERE BetfairMark = $BetfairMarketID), '2', (select BBack FROM game WHERE id = $id)),
            {
            ((SELECT id FROM auctions WHERE BetfairMark = $BetfairMarketID), '3', (select DrawBack FROM game WHERE id = $id))
            }
 }
    }
}
");`